# ajax ie8 not firing callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-8

Environment: winXP, vs08, ie8

why is my callback not firing?

```
<div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="myjs()" />
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myjs() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                xhrCallback(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.open("POST", "Handler.ashx", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("x=" + 1 + "&y=" + 2);
    }

    function xhrCallback(retval) {
        alert('test');
    }

</script>
```

Comment: it goes to and from server just fine

Comment: Is it even making it to the `onreadystatechange`'s handler? Can you debug so you can see what the values of `readyState` and `status` are every time that fires?

Comment: I tried it (in IE9) in IE8 and IE7 modes, and it worked fine. I would expect it to work fine in real IE8.

Comment: Is the status 200 ? Ideally it should be hitting the callback method.

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes it makes it into that handler and I get status code 12030 and readyState = 4. Looking that up now.

Comment: ok, so if I publish the website to iis that's on same machine, the ajax works fine. Why not with Cassini?